# Change default iPython in homebrew to use Python 2.x.x instead of Python 3.x.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, homebrew, jupyter

I used homebrew to install python 2.x.x and python 3.x.x

I installed several package for both Python versions using the pip2 and pip3 commands.

One of the packages I installed was iPython.

Now, my default python command (i.e when I write `python`in the command line= points to Homebrew 2.x.x python, but my default `ipython` command uses Python 3.x.x for some reason I can't understand.

How can I change this? I'm trying to use `hydrogen` package in `atom`to use `jupyter` but I'm doing a Python 2.x.x project and `hydrogen` keeps trying to run it using Python 3.x.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

Simply copy the `ipython2` file to `ipython`:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/ipython2 /usr/local/bin/ipython
```